# Angular handle property which can be number or observable<number>

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created an interface with a method which can return a number or an `observable<number>` (`number|observable<number>`). The problem is now that I want to display the value of the method in my template and I do not know how to do that.
The problem is that I need the async pipe if the return value is an observable but with the return value number, I do not need the pipe. Any ideas how to handle that in the template file?

Comment: i need async pipe if the return value is an observable

Comment: 1. put `propertyX` on component, 2. add another `methodX` that will update `propertyX` directly if return type is `number` or subscribe to observable and in its success callback update `propertyX`. bind `propertyX` to template

Comment: I had this idea also but this does not work because the property is only set once if it is a number. The think is that the method returns the length from an array. And if I add a item to the array the method should return the new length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the returning number into an `Observable` inside your method. Like:

```
if(value instanceof Observable) {
  return value;
}
return Observable.of(value);
```

Now your method always returns an `Observable` and you can use the `async` pipe.

Another way would be to create a getter which does the same.

Comment: This is what I would do. All things observable! But it also really makes the implementation more straight forward.